# Why does Android Studio not run my generateConfig but command line does

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to generate identical assets for each of the subprojects in a project.  Since exactly the same thing has to happen for each subproject, I'm trying to avoid having to add the generation code to each subproject.

What I've got so far is:

```
// in my outer build.gradle
allprojects { proj ->
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        def configTemplate = project.file('src/main/templates/configuration.json')
        def android = proj.getProperties()['android']

        if (configTemplate.exists() && android != null) {
            task generateConfigFiles(type: ConfigureTask) {
                template configTemplate
                environments proj.rootProject.file('scripts/environments.json')
                environmentName host
                destination new File(project.buildDir, 'templates/configuration.json')
            }

            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.mergeAssets.dependsOn generateConfigFiles
            }
        }
    }
}

// each application build.gradle
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDir 'build/templates'
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work exactly as expected when I run gradle from the command line `./gradlew mergeQaDebugAssets` runs the `generateConfigFiles` task before running `mergeQaDebugAssets`

If I attempt to run this from Android Studio using the gradle window, it never runs `generateConfigFiles`

I've also gotten it to work by just including the `projectsEvaluated` step in each of the project `build.gradle` files, but, as noted, I'm trying to avoid the code duplication and maintenance headaches that brings.